# MacBook Pro A1707 Logic Board Upgrade/Replacement

Tags: macbook-pro, ssd, upgrade, logicboard

I have an A1707 (15" 2017 MacBook Pro) with 2.8GHz and 256GB working flawlessly, but I want to upgrade the SSD, because it's filling to capacity every month.

So, can I replace my logic board with another one that has a 3.1Ghz and 2TB drive? Or, can I only replace it with another 2.8Ghz with 512GB instead?

Comment: Yes: the logic board is "all the computer", and the CPU/storage is the only difference between the models of the same MBP. You might want to check sites like ifixit.com and everymac.com, though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Yes, you can replace the logic board of the same MacBook Pro vintage.

If you are replacing a 2017 15-inch MacBook Pro logic board with another 2017 15-inch MacBook Pro logic board with faster CPU and more drive capacity, then yes, you can swap them out.   In fact, this is what Apple does if you have them replace a logic board due to failure/damage (if they don't convince you to buy a new unit, that is).

#### Important consideration

If you are purchasing this logic board on the secondary market (eBay, FB Marketplace, etc.) **make sure that the device has been dissociated from the previous owners Apple ID**.  If they don't do this, you could be locked out of the device and it would forever be attached to the other user.